# Get ID3 tag from MP3 Streaming

Tags: javascript, php, mp3, id3, webradio

I encounter difficulties in recovering informations (ID3 tag) from an [MP3 stream](http://radiomed.ice.infomaniak.ch/radiomed.mp3). I want this informations for display the albumArt and the title of the current song on the homepage of the radiomed's website.

**Update**

---

With PHP , I worked with ID3 library for PHP, but this library was not up to date since 2004 and with Javascript , I worked with TagLib, MusicMetadata and id3js . The results were errors messages (js) and string (0) with a `var_dump($getID3)` // this return the object obtain with the catched info from the stream .

The result should be, title and artist of the current on air song.

I tried with php & js but I failed.

Comment: What library did you use ? What is the result, what should the result be ?

Comment: With PHP , I worked with  ID3 library for PHP, but this library was not up to date since 2004 and with Javascript , I worked with  TagLib, MusicMetadata and id3js . The results were errors messages (js) and string (0) with a var_dump($getID3) // this return the object obtain with the catched info from the stream .

Comment: The result should be, title and artist of the current on air song.

Comment: You should edit your question and add some code sample which gives you trouble.

Comment: Added update from comment into question for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example can help you
https://gist.github.com/fracasula/5781710

But it won t read the stream conitnuously, it will just fetch first buffer and try it.
It may or may not returns the current track name, it depends.

It needs to be improved, i guess, to read stream in continue and detect each buffer for track data.
Thus you could show it wherever needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use PECL extension if you want to fetch id3 directly from mp3

```
pecl install id3-0.2
```

And than use a [id3_get_tag](https://php.net/manual/en/function.id3-get-tag.php) function:

```
<?php
   $tag = id3_get_tag( "path/to/example.mp3" );
   print_r($tag);
?>
```

But instead doing this, i would search documentation of your streaming software, probably there is some api to fetch stream data (json, xml, plain text)